# Сортировка слиянием

Tags: сортировка

Что значит по сортировке этим методом, отсортированный файл?

Данные выводятся же не по алфавиту, а вот по какому признаку? Как он их сортирует?

Пример

AAAASGFSPMZJKSSQQZVZCONCEWLVJGQBXANIAKDVXKJSEUBHTQ
AAABWTHNVYEZYMWFPYRWVPTNNNTQYWPMPICZNGISLIJKGVOGZI
AAAJZZLKNWPYYUOFDUVJYZMGTXSQCAXSPNARXJBEIFUEEDQNHR
AABFGMYSLMSTHXFVNSHHDMZIYRDPEUMHTNGEVYHDSDVRBWSCTA

Answer (score 1):

[@bob](/users/19007/bob), пригядитесь внимательней и Вы заметите

```
AAAA < AAAB < AAAJ < AAB
```

в первых 3-х строках одинаковое начало -- `AAA`, а в последной уже `AAB`.